# Need help getting a sidebar container to span the length of a page (HTML5/CSS3)

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/3nAJ8/1/

If you see the example above, the sidebar doesn't continue down all the way to the footer. That's what I want it to do, no matter how much content is in the main container to the right.

I have tried thing like this in CSS
    `aside { height: 100%; }`

but to no avail.

I was hoping somebody would be able to help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following lines:

```
bottom:0px;
float:bottom;
height: 100%;
top: ?? whatever you want! ;
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Thanks for your help and the quick reply though!